# Realm Results not auto-updating

Tags: swift, realm

I've got 2 models- Cards and Channels - and a Channel owns Cards

```
class Card : Object {
    let channel = LinkingObjects(fromType: Channel.self, property: "cards")
}

class Channel: Object {
    let cards = List<Card>()
}
```

In my UICollectionViewController, I'm using this as my Results:

```
var results: Results<Card> = {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    return realm.objects(Card).filter("ANY channel.is_following = true")
        .filter("ANY channel.live = true")
        .filter("published == true AND retracted == false").sorted("published_at", ascending: false)

}()
```

and my notification block set in my viewDidLoad:

```
notificationToken = results.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
            print("in notif block")
}
```

I'm trying to make use of the new RealmCollectionChange features, but when I make a write/change to a Channel it isn't reflected in my Card results which should trigger the notification block. It shows the right stuff at first launch / initialization, but doesn't keep up with the changes after that. My pre-RealmCollectionChange code still works fine for me (catch all notifications and manually refresh my results), but wanted to see if anyone has any pointers before I roll back. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the calculated `results`? Have you tried a direct assignment? You could have `realm` in a separated service.

Comment: @catalandres I was doing a direct assignment when I was catching all notifications, and I can always roll back to that to get it working. I was just trying out this Fine Grained Notifications thing they released, but wasn't sure if my results have too many chained filters? https://realm.io/news/marin-todorov-fine-grained-notifications/

Comment: @iantheparker, I don't see any reason that the code you've provided should not work. Would you mind filing an issue on the [Realm Cocoa GitHub repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) with more detail so we can investigate?